# is this proper sql?

Tags: sql

I have some coupon software for an e-commerce site. I want to generate a bunch of coupons at once. It consists of 2 tables. 1 for the coupon, and 1 for the coupon description. The primary key being coupon_id.

Is this the proper way to do the sql? Will the coupon_id match up? Since it is auto-incremented and I am not inputting a number I think it should.

edit: I just rechecked and only the coupon_id field in coupons table is auto incremented not the one in coupon_description

But I'm not sure if using 2 inserts is the proper way.

```
   INSERT INTO  coupons (
    coupon_id,
    coupon_type,
    coupon_code,
    coupon_amount,
    coupon_minimum_order,
    coupon_start_date,
    coupon_expire_date,
    uses_per_coupon,
    uses_per_user,
    restrict_to_products,
    restrict_to_categories,
    restrict_to_customers,
    coupon_active,
    date_created,
    date_modified
    )
    VALUES (
    '' , '',  '" . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8) ."', '100' , '1' , '06/05/2013' , '06/11/2013' , '1' ,  '1',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '')

    INSERT INTO coupons_description (
    coupon_id,
    language_id,
    coupon_name,
    coupon_description
    )

    VALUES (
    '', '1', 'test coupon', 'test'  

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only one is auto-incremented, I would insert into that table first, then look up the value and hard-code it into the dependant table.  That is:

```
INSERT INTO  coupons (
coupon_type,
coupon_code,
...)
VALUES ('',  '" . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8) ."', '100' ,...).
```

Notice that coupon_id is NOT in the insert statement.  The database will assign that itself (assuming the auto-increment is doing what it should).  Some databases let you assign this, but I consider that bad form.  The problem, then, is finding that record again.  I'd use:

```
select * from coupons order by coupon_id desc;
```

Unless someone else is adding coupons at the same time, you should see your coupon on top.  It would help if you used a unique coupon name or description.  Anyway, you'll have to take the assigned ID and then update the table WITHOUT the auto-increment:

```
INSERT INTO coupons_description (
coupon_id,
language_id,
coupon_name,
coupon_description)

VALUES ('123', '1', 'test coupon', 'test')
```

Where '123' is really whatever coupon_id you found from the select statement.

But your syntax does look correct, otherwise.

Comment: I went with this and just set the loop to start at the last value I checked in the database. Not the best way of doing this probably. And I think the tables should probably be combined but I didn't have time to rework the code that goes with it. Anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I may go 'coupons' table check biggest coupon_id and specify the new id in insert explicitly. I think this is a safer way to prevent any mismatching.

let's say you have 100 coupon in coupons already. So in your case:

```
INSERT INTO  coupons (
    coupon_id,
    coupon_type,
    ...
) VALUES (101 , '', ...);

INSERT INTO coupons_description (
    coupon_id,
    language_id,
    coupon_name,
    coupon_description
) VALUES (101, '1', 'test coupon', 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either merging the two tables (they appear to have a 1:1 relationship) or changing the description table so that coupon_id is a foreign key of the first table, and remove the autoincrement. After that you can insert into the first table, then instead of trying to guess the id to insert into the second table, you just use select @@identity; (or select scope_identity(); if on sql server)